# How to auto increment the id in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, auto-increment

Is there any way to auto increment the id in oracle?

**UPDATE:** It's working but the sequence start in 2 instead of 1. I already set the sequence start with 1

If it possible not use the sequence but still id's will be auto increment?

Here:

```
  CREATE TABLE tblname
  ( 
   fieldname_id number(25),
   contract_number number(12) not null,
   CONSTRAINT letter_status_pk PRIMARY KEY (fieldname_id, contract_number)
  );
```

Sequence w/trigger:

```
  create sequence fieldname_id_sequence start with 1
  increment by 1
  minvalue 1;

  create trigger tr_tblname
  before insert on tblname               
  for each row  
  begin   
  select fieldname_id_sequence.nextval into :NEW.fieldname_id from dual;
  end;
```

insert data:

```
insert all
  into tblname(contract_number,fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3,fieldname4,fieldname5,fieldname6,fieldname7,fieldname8,fieldname8,fieldname10,fieldname11) values(3300026224,'values','values','values','3/12/2014','values','values','3/18/2014','3/7/2014','values','values')
  into tblname(contract_number,fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3,fieldname4,fieldname5,fieldname6,fieldname7,fieldname8,fieldname8,fieldname10,fieldname11) values (3300016335,'values','values','values','3/12/2014','values','values','3/18/2014','3/7/2014','values','values')
  select 1 from dual;
```

Comment: Could you please craft your example carefully so that the object names at least matched. You create table `test`, then create trigger for `tblname` and insert into it. After all - the structures don't match. I understand you need it QUICKLY but please spend some time and rework it.

Comment: This should work as you did it - please provide a [full, minimal example](http://sscce.org) with expected and actual output, ideally on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Using a sequence **is** the way to do this in Oracle, best to focus on getting that working. You've two underscores in the sequence name when you create it, and only one where you reference it in the trigger - perhaps your problem is as simple as that?

Comment: @zerkms: Maybe the table names not matching is even the problem...

Comment: Indeed, both sequence names and table names don't match.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: I don't expect people to be that... how to say that politely... unexperienced :-)

Comment: @zerkms: You are long enough here to not be surprised any more. ;)

Comment: `IDENTITY COLUMNS` in `Oracle12c`?

Comment: @zerkms sorry typo error. It fixed now. Is there anyway to auto increment the id without using sequence?

Comment: "without using sequence" --- any technical reason to not use sequences? Btw, now columns don't match. Could you please try **ALL** your queries first before your next question revision?

Comment: @User014019 If the only reason you have for not using a sequence is that it didn't work the first time you tried, then I can only wish you the very very best of luck in solving a problem that Oracle has so neatly solved for you already.

Comment: @zerkms it's working now but the start of sequence is 2 instead of 1. I try not to use sequence just not to make the script not complicated hmm

Comment: @User014019: if it starts with 2 then something increments it

Comment: but i set the sequence like this start with 1 increment by 1 minvalue 1, but the sequence still start in 2

Answer (score 1):

you can model it easily with a sequence and a trigger:

```
Create sequence sequence_name start with value increment by value minvalue value maxvalue value;
```

First, let’s create an emp table with primary key constraint on emp_id column.

```
SQL> create table emp ( emp_id number(10),
fname varchar2(25),
lname varchar2(25),
constraint pk_emp_id PRIMARY KEY(emp_id)
);
```

Now let’s create a sequence.

```
SQL> Create sequence emp_sequence start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 10000;
```

Now we have created a sequence object named emp_sequence with starting value as 1 and incrementing by 1 from 1 (minvalue) to 10000 (maxvalue)

```
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Darvin','Johnson'); SQL> 
insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Mig','Andrews');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Alex','Martin');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Jon','paul');
SQL> insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(emp_sequence.nextval,'Yatin','Bones');
```

In emp_sequence.nextval where emp_sequence is the name of sequence we created above and nextval is a function that is used to assign the next number from emp_sequence to emp_id column in emp table.

Comment: Identity columns exist in Oracle 12c

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle 12c** introduces `IDENTITY COLUMNS`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE new_identity_table
  2    (
  3      ID   NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4      text VARCHAR2(50)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT
  2  INTO new_identity_table
  3    (
  4      text
  5    )
  6    VALUES
  7    (
  8      'This table has an identity column'
  9    );

1 row created.

SQL> column text format A40;
SQL>
SQL> select * from new_identity_table;

        ID TEXT
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 This table has an identity column

SQL>
```

Oracle creates a `sequence` to populate the `identity column`. You can find it named as `ISEQ$$`

```
SQL> select sequence_name, min_value, max_value, increment_by from user_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME         MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE                     INCREMENT_BY
-------------------- ---------- ----------------------------   ------------
ISEQ$$_93199                  1 9999999999999999999999999999   1

SQL>
```

More more information about the identity columns, use the `ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS` view.

```
SQL> SELECT table_name,
  2         column_name,
  3         generation_type,
  4         identity_options
  5  FROM   all_tab_identity_cols
  6  WHERE  owner = 'LALIT'
  7  ORDER BY 1, 2;

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME     GENERATION IDENTITY_OPTIONS
-------------------- --------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
NEW_IDENTITY_TABLE   ID              ALWAYS     START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999
                                                999999999999999999999, MIN_VALUE: 1, CYCLE_FLAG: N
                                                , CACHE_SIZE: 20, ORDER_FLAG: N


SQL>
```

Comment: I have an error SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

Comment: Your oracle version? Post results from `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`

Comment: `11.2.0.4` does not have `identity columns`. Introduced with `12.1.0.1`